# Engine Controller Design

Tags: engine-theory

I'm wondering if there are books/articles or perhaps an open source project on the theory and design of engine controllers (ECUs)? It seems like designing an ECU could be a fun project and I'm also curious to know how they work and I think it would be helpful to be able to think about how ECUs typically work when troubleshooting.

Comment: interesting read on the 80's dodge ECUs - http://thedodgegarage.com/turbo_pfi.html

Comment: I've actually considered how hard this would be.  I've done some work with the arduino and I am a software developer.  I was considering buying an arduino and having it read a few engine sensors, and output data to the screen or log to a file.  I was planning more on using it for datalogging, but once it has the inputs, you can start building outputs.  Was wondering if I could use this for a carb to TBI swap.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this myself for a project and found an [open-source ECU](http://www.diyefi.org/). It's been ported to [39 different vehicles](http://forum.diyefi.org/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=1568) so far, [7 of which](http://forum.diyefi.org/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=1838) are claimed to be daily-drivers.